# prettyphoto - jquery gallery plugin - image can not be loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

I have very weird behaviour on my site

[www.zrubex.eu](http://www.zrubex.eu)

I've implemented PrettyPhoto gallery and on local server (wamp) everything works fine, but when I upload it to web server, only two of 42 images displays in full size after clicking on the thumbnail. It's 5th and 8th.

I researched it with firebug and it's trying to get three images after click on one image - the clicked one, previous and next. But the problem is, that it cannot find the image and displays warning that the path was not found. I don't know why those 2 images work and others don't.

Comment: Probably because those images are only on your local machine.

Comment: I was. It's very difficult to diagnose an issue without seeing relevant code posted here or in a jsFiddle.

Comment: Is it difficult to see the code of the site mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension is capitalized thus making it not find the image.

I was watching your requests and its trying to request `http://www.zrubex.eu/images/DSC00895.JPG`... which of course doesn't exist.

But `http://www.zrubex.eu/images/DSC00895.jpg` does exist.

You have:

```
<a href="images/DSC00895.JPG" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery2]" title=""><img src="images/DSC00895t.jpg" width="96" height="96" alt=""></a>
```

Fix the extension for the larger image and it will work.

```
<a href="images/DSC00895.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery2]" title=""><img src="images/DSC00895t.jpg" width="96" height="96" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: I cant believe that I didnt notice it myself. Thank you!